# Regular Expression to detect query in java

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to search a String using Regular Expression.
For example: this is my sample String

```
  **if (c == 0) {
                count = 0;
                du.insert(ipAddress, c);
            } else {
                count = c;
            }
            getDate();
            String query1 = "select * from loginmaster where  username = '" + username + "' and password = '" + password + "' ;";
            //out.println(query1);
            //out.println(request.getParameter("Group1"));
            session.setAttribute("group", request.getParameter("Group1"));
            if (count < 3) {
                if (request.getParameter("Group1").equals("With")) {
                    LoginQuery q = new LoginQuery();
                    checked = q.Checker(query1);
                    if (checked == false) {
                        connection.getConnection();
                        connection.getDML("insert into attack values('"+ipAddress+"','"+date+"','Attack Detected')");
                    }
                }**
```

and i am trying to find querys in this String using Regular Expression

```
String regExp = "\b(ALTER|CREATE|DELETE|DROP|EXEC(UTE){0,1}|INSERT( +INTO){0,1}|MERGE|SELECT|UPDATE|UNION( +ALL){0,1})\b";
```

and

```
String regExp = "(;|\\s)(exec|execute|select|insert|update|delete|create|alter|drop|rename|truncate|backup|restore)\\s";
```

But i am not getting any Output nor Error.

Remaining Code is:

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regExp, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);                
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
                    if (m.matches()) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "innnnnnnnnnn");
                        System.err.println(m.group(1));
                    }
}
```

Pls help

Comment: The proper way to prevent SQL injection when allowing arbitrary statements is to restrict the user's permission.

Comment: I just want to Search For Query from Source String using regular expression. dats it

Answer (score 0):

Your regexes will not match with the input string, because of **case mismatch**.

Your regular expressions written in upper-case but your input string contains lower-case matches. So, either make the regexes **case-insensitive** or convert it to **lower-case**.

By the way, your regexes couldn't separate query `insert into attack ...` and method: `du.insert(ipAddress, c);`